# Opening up a fragment in full screen from a child fragment(Non Full screen) using Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-navigation-graph, android-navigation-editor

Here is my design requirement my first screen is an activity which contains a Fragment(Non-Fullscreen)  on clicking a filter icon in a fragment(Non-Full screen), I want to navigate to filter fragment(Fullscreen) without communicating with an activity using Android Navigation Component

[image: picture]

Comment: have you tried changing the height and width of the container dynamically after changing to a full screen Fragment?